What key points should one consider when composing a piano accompaniment?

Here is a simple melody and accompaniment I wrote in F minor and for the first time I wanted to write something away from 4 part-chorales which I have been learing over the past 3 years. I like the way the LH sounds with the melody even though the amount of notes in each chord vary. Sometimes there are only 2 notes and other times there are 3. THe question is: What are the key things to consider when writing a piano accompaniment like this and can this one be improved somehow while respecting the rhythm and chords used? Out of my original 4-part piano sketch (chorale voice leading) I only used the bass and melody and discarded the inner voices and recomposed the LH part as a separate exercise based on the dissonance and elaboration of the melody notes. Not sure if this is the best way or not but I found that trying to keep the voices from my piano sketch and transposing them down an octave didn't sound as good as what I have now because of the dissonances I had on the melody after I elaborated it. I needed a LH part that was fairly comfortable for an intermediate pianist to play that sounded as good as possible for this melody. I was going for a Mozart-style accompaniment.

It might help if you show the corresponding four bars from the initial chorale.

You could write an entire book on this topic! But, some particular things come to my mind. Most of it seems to fall under the umbrella idea: piano texture does not treat harmony with the same strictness of voices compared to a chorale.
Compared to four part chorales classical piano is often just two essential parts. Four real parts could be reduced to two, like this...

In terms of working from a four part chorale outline to a classical piano treatment, those two things are saying the same thing despite the difference in voicing.
Jumping between octaves is common and treats the keyboard sort of like orchestral groups. The simple I V6 idea above can be placed into separate octaves...

You can think of that as bass and tenor then moving to soprano, but it probably makes more sense to think orchestrally. It is using the keyboard ranges to mimic brass followed by high winds.
Classical piano style includes melody with accompaniment, for example Alberti bass accompaniment with a melodic line, but it's common to join the hands in figuration patterns or simple doublings.
A full and obvious Alberti bass style accompaniment...

...but that harmony could also be realized in these ways...

For those two examples the LH is so simple, barely an accompaniment. It makes more sense to think of it as a rhythmic figuration of a chord progression (I V6) distributed over two hands.
OK. That gives us some ideas for relaxing the strict sense of voices and the sense that there must be strictly delineated melody with accompaniment. Does this have any bearing on what you wrote? Maybe, but we need something to guide our choices.
When I look through my score of Mozart piano sonatas, and pay attention to the rhythmic interaction between the RH and LH, I notice a tendency to avoid starting and stopping both hands on strong beats. It is not an absolute rule, but this avoidance happens a lot. There are two ways to achieve it: one of the hands can take a rest, or the melodic line uses motion before and after the bar line.
The music you have so far is a bit heavy with both hands starting and stopping on the beat...

I think your music could be compared with K. 310, because of the minor key and the block chord idea in the LH, but notice how Mozart lightened the emphasis on strong beats by making the melody in the RH extend after and begin before the bar line...

If you tried to get the same rhythmic interaction of the hands, it might be like this...

...that softens the strong down beat feel and also provides a little three step-wise sixteenth note motif.
But, that does not actual deal with accompaniment. If we turn our attention to the accompaniment, and take a cue from K. 311, we could try using rests in the LH on strong beats.
Mozart did this...

If you try something similar, you might do this...

I took some additional liberties with that edit. You start the first two measures on a dissonant tone, which is a bit odd in classical style, so I just used a rest at that point too. You don't need constant accompaniment and this seem like a good opportunity to drop the accompaniment, avoid the dissonance, and lighten the down beat feel even more. Also, beats 3 and 4 of bar 3 seemed a bit busy in the RH and inactive in the LH. Another way to break out of a rigid accompaniment is to let the LH take over as the main line. I used a rest on the onset of beat 3 but then made the LH mimic the idea from the RH of beats 1 and 2. In bar 4 the sixteenth rhythm is removed, rests are used in the LH, and the composite rhythm is steady eighths. The simplification of the rhythm reinforces the sense of repose at that cadence point. Overall the rhythmic interaction follow the plan of a musical sentence: a simple idea repeated, an increase in complexity, a resolution.
I am not claiming these two revisions are better. They are merely what I came up with as solutions to make the original idea conform to the kind of rhythmic interaction between LH and RH (accompaniment and melody) in examples from Mozart's piano sonatas.
The only other thing I want to add is a caution about trying to work up a four part chorale idea into a Mozart like piano style. Assuming that sonata form (or some elaboration of binary form) is the aim of a Mozart styled piano piece, understand that chorales and sonatas have different phrase structures.
I think the application of four part chorales in a sonata setting would be for just the essential voice leading of individual phrases. (In other words, make sure your sonata phrases clearly reduce to simple voice leading norms.) For any non-sequential phrase that will probably involve a progression of just 3 or 4 chords. For many classical works it will be just 2 chords: tonic and dominant. The harmonic rhythm for those passages might be slow, for example, at the half note level. The creative part will be how those harmonic outlines are realized rhythmically. And finally, the classical sonata style will repeat short phrases with some kind of variation. That type of phrase repeating doesn't really happen in chorales. So, your chorale might provide a sort of palette of harmonic progressions, but not a design of phrase structure.

The first example, the low C and E accompanying a treble clef E, is hardly to be recommended.  Partly for the muddy voicing, partly because there's good reason for the rule against doubling a major 3rd.

@Laurence, I removed that part. There are examples to be found, but I overstated my pet peeve. You're right, it isn't the norm.

Lovely thank you for your effort

@armani, I've been studying this topic, and other related part writing ideas, recently, so it is something I like to dig into!
